# View doesnt resize on rotation

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xamarin.forms

I have `shared app` in `xamarin.forms`

with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyFin1.Views.Reports
{
    public class Reports_view : ContentPage
    {
        StackLayout Lay = new StackLayout();
    public Reports_view ()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
        Lay.Children.Add(
              new Xamarin.Forms.Label
              {
                  Text = "Мои Финансы",
                  TextColor = Color.FromRgb(200, 200, 200),
                  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                  VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                  FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Label)),
                  FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic,
                  BackgroundColor=Color.Aqua
              }
           );
        Button Bar_chart_go = new Button
        {
            Text = "Динамика",
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        Button Pie_chart_go = new Button
        {
            Text = "Структура",
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        Bar_chart_go.Clicked += Bar_chart_go_Clicked;
        Pie_chart_go.Clicked += Pie_chart_go_Clicked;

        Lay.Children.Add(Bar_chart_go);
        Lay.Children.Add(Pie_chart_go);

        Content = new StackLayout {
            BackgroundColor=Color.Maroon,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

            Children = {

                Lay
            }
        };    
    }
}
```

on Android emulator all works good ( when rotate screen -- view rotated)
[image]

[image]

On Windows Phone (nokia 530) there is problem:

[image]

[image]

In `MainPage.xaml.cs` i have `SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.PortraitOrLandscape;`

If i rotate and then navigate to page all works good.
[image]

Is there way to fix it?

## Additional Info

Xamarin.Forms 2.0.1.6505

PS original question on [RU_SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501787/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: What version of Xamarin Forms are you working with? 2.1 introduced [quite a few issues](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61867/xamarin-forms-2-1-0-released/p1) for people.

Comment: No I meant that 2.1 may cause more issues so be careful if you do update. I was going to suggest downgrading if you already had 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

Inside your constructor:

```
this.SizeChanged += ModalPage_SizeChanged;
```

Then:

```
void ModalPage_SizeChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WidthRequest = Width;
    this.HeightRequest = Height;

    Lay.WidthRequest = Width;
    Lay.HeightRequest = Height;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed. in debug width and Height changed , but view cut ( as on image part of button cut)

Comment: What about setting the Width and Height of the buttons? also can you set the BackGroundColor property of each element to see which one is the one that is being cut?

Comment: Also do you have `HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` on all your components? ContentPage, StakLayout, Buttons etc...

Comment: Added images in color ( cuted all objects).. `HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` -- not helps( ContentPage -hasnt such attribute)

Comment: Ok, so the problem is the ContentPage, using `HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` and `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` inside the Stacklayout and what about setting the WidthRequest and HeightRequest to a fixed size just for testing purposes for example: 1080 and 920 to double check if the ContentPage is being resized and redrawn.

Comment: tried.. nothing changed i see  `WidthRequest=1080` and   `HeightRequest=920` but view not changed ( tried for Lay and ContentPage)